# How to Fire Personal Event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I can't fire personal events using JavaScript in IE. In Firefox work great.

My code is:

```
var evento; 
if(document.createEventObject)  
{  
   evento = document.createEventObject();  
   document.fireEvent('eventoPersonal', evento);     
}  
//FF  
else  
{  
    evento = document.createEvent('Events');  
    evento.initEvent('eventoPersonal',true,false);  
    document.dispatchEvent(evento);  
}
```

But when try to execute `document.fireEvent('eventoPersonal', evento);` in IE, it doesn't work. How can I fire **NO custom** events in IE?

In Internet Explorer I get the error: "Invalid arguments" in the line where execute  `document.fireEvent('eventoPersonal', evento);`

Comment: Cool. What do you mean in IE "not work"? Do you get an error? Does nothing happen but no error?

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know why I forget "NO", because I really pregunts "How do I fire NO custom events in Internet Explorer?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider using a library to abstract this.  Both prototype an jquery will handle this for you.  Jquery is especially good at allowing you to create an event with very simple code.

Jquery's documentation is available here:
http://docs.jquery.com/Events

Comment: Yes, but HOW do these frameworks implement custom event names in IE?

Answer (score 39):

Dean Edward's describes how to fire cutsom events in IE

http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2009/03/callbacks-vs-events/

Its near the bottom of the article

```
var currentHandler;

if (document.addEventListener) {

  // We've seen this code already

} else if (document.attachEvent) { // MSIE

  document.documentElement.fakeEvents = 0; // an expando property

  document.documentElement.attachEvent("onpropertychange", function(event) {
    if (event.propertyName == "fakeEvents") {
      // execute the callback
      currentHandler();
    }
  });

  dispatchFakeEvent = function(handler) {
    // fire the propertychange event
    document.documentElement.fakeEvents++;
  };
}
```

Comment: +1 This is EXACTLY what he is asking about, and even though it's technically a workaround, it is exactly what the original poster was asking for. (good find!)

Comment: Great answer, I was actually looking at prototype to see how they did it (see answer below) but this is a great example and article! +50 rep awarded (when SO lets me, says 3 hours...) :D

Comment: Just for the record, document.documentElement.fakeEvents++; doesnt fire onpropertychange Event on IE9, it has to be  document.documentElement.setAttribute("fakeEvent", document.documentElement.fakeEvents++);

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is - in IE you **can not** fire events that are not on this list:

[MSDN - DHTML Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533051.aspx)

From what I can gather, frameworks store a registry of the "custom" event names and you must use their implementation specific *trigger* and *handle* functions for custom events. For example, prototype uses the `ondatavailable` event to pass through their custom events behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

In IE11 document.dispatchEvent still doesn't work, but now attachEvent is missing too, so the other solution is not going to work either. However, I came up with one even uglier. :) It involves replacing the addEventListener method and goes on like this:

```
var oldEventListener = document.addEventListener;

document.addEventListener = function (event, func, capture) {
    if (event == "MyPreciousCustomEvent") {
        document.MyPreciousCustomEvent = func;
    }

    oldEventListener.call(document, event, func, capture);
};

...

$(function () {
    try {
        document.MyPreciousCustomEvent("MyPreciousCustomEvent", {});
    } catch (e) {}
});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

As I read the relevant MSDN article page on the createEventObject method, it appears as though it isn't used for creating custom event - it is used for creating custom objects that can be passed to already existing events.

**Description**: 
Generates an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863(VS.85).aspx) object to pass event context information when you use the [fireEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423(VS.85).aspx) method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536390%28VS.85%29.aspx

**Update**: You are getting the "invalid arguments" error because 'eventoPersonal' is not an acceptable event to fire.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know why I forget "NO", because I really pregunts "How do I fire NO custom events in Internet Explorer?"

Answer (score -2):

Yeah referring to @Don Albrecht, you can use jquery trigger() method more on http://api.jquery.com/trigger/