# What is the behavior of addEventListener when you try and add a non-existent event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

For example:

```
someElement.addEventListener("blahblah", alert("hello!"));
```

When typed into both the Chrome and Firefox development consoles seems to fire the `alert("hello!")` call once and then return '`undefined`'.

If I embed that same call into the page, then nothing seems to happen - no error is fired, no interesting value is returned, etc.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-registration doesn't list any exceptions thrown, so presumably nothing should happen. Individual browser behavior might be unpredictable though.

Comment: Also, that `undefined` you are talking about in the console is the return value of the addEventListener function call, which as per the w3c docs is `undefined`

Comment: what is `blahblah`? what are you expecting that code should do?!?!?!

Comment: the second parameter must be a function; `alert("hello!")` is not a function! it is a call to the alert function which returns `undefined`.

Comment: Your code should be `.addEventListener("blahblah", function() { alert("hello"); });` You forgot to add `function() {}` which made the `alert` function execute immediately.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "nonexistent event type", there are only event types waiting to be used in `initEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a custom event, which can be [also be fired](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2028456/1048572).

However, the problem you got in your test is that you need to pass a function as a handler, not `undefined` which the invoked `alert()` returns. Try these:

```
el.addEventListener("foo", alert.bind(window, "hello!"));
```

or

```
el.addEventListener("bar", function(e){ alert("hello "+e.name); });
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I didn't know about custom events. That explains it.